# Where is the constructor of a stylus contract defined?

Tags: rust, stylus

In solidity, I can pick the deployment parameters of my smart contract using the `constructor` keyword.

```js
constructor( /* params here */) {...}
```

What is the rust/stylus equivalent of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently [no support](https://docs.arbitrum.io/stylus/troubleshooting-building-stylus#why-are-constructors-not-yet-supported-for-stylus-contracts) for constructors in Stylus. The suggested approach is to call an `init` function after deployment.